# FFMPEG does not add images to audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a slideshow with a background music by `ffmpeg`, and use the command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i map.txt -i audio.flac -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 video.mp4
```

and map.txt is like

```
file '1.jpg'
duration 15
file '2.jpg'
duration 60
```

The result is a video with the audio and blank background. If I run the above command without audio as

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i map.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 video.mp4
```

a perfect video of the images (the intended slideshow) is generated (but obviously without audio).

I reckon the problem is related to synchronising the audio and images.

This is the terminal output for the first command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i map.txt -i audio.flac -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 video.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x1cc8d40] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, concat, from 'map.txt':
  Duration: 00:05:48.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, flac, from 'audio.flac':
  Metadata:
    TITLE           : Speak to Me
    ARTIST          : Creator
    ALBUM           : Acoustic Hits
    track           : 14
    GENRE           : Pop
    DATE            : 2011
  Duration: 00:03:31.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1026 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (16 bit), 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mjpeg @ 0x7fe688001ba0] Changeing bps to 8
frame=    2 fps=0.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3593kB time=00:03:31.02 bitrate= 139.5kbits/s    
video:147kB audio:3410kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.036417%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] frame I:1     Avg QP: 2.55  size: 33683
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] frame P:1     Avg QP:19.33  size:116022
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] mb I  I16..4: 89.7%  1.1%  9.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] mb P  I16..4:  0.9%  1.8% 30.1%  P16..4:  1.4%  1.5%  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:63.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] 8x8 transform intra:2.1% inter:15.2%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 19.7% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 2.8% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  2%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 12% 39%  1%  1%  2%  1%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 43% 16% 16%  3%  4%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1ccdf80] kb/s:20.65
```

**UPDATE** (following the comment suggestion)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i map.txt -i audio.flac -vsync vfr -r 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 video.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x1fe9d80] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, concat, from 'map.txt':
  Duration: 00:02:28.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, flac, from 'audio.flac':
  Metadata:
    TITLE           : Speak to Me
    ARTIST          : Creator
    ALBUM           : Acoustic Hits
    track           : 14
    GENRE           : Pop
    DATE            : 2011
  Duration: 00:03:31.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1026 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 5 fps, 10240 tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (16 bit), 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mjpeg @ 0x7f74cc001ba0] Changeing bps to 8
frame=    2 fps=0.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3593kB time=00:03:31.02 bitrate= 139.5kbits/s    
video:147kB audio:3410kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.036417%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] frame I:1     Avg QP: 2.55  size: 33683
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] frame P:1     Avg QP:19.33  size:116022
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] mb I  I16..4: 89.7%  1.1%  9.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] mb P  I16..4:  0.9%  1.8% 30.1%  P16..4:  1.4%  1.5%  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:63.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] 8x8 transform intra:2.1% inter:15.2%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 19.7% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 2.8% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  2%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 12% 39%  1%  1%  2%  1%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 43% 16% 16%  3%  4%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1feefc0] kb/s:20.65
```

Comment: Share full log of the failed command.

Comment: @Mulvya I updated the question with the terminal output.

Comment: You'll need more frames for most players. Add `-r 5`

Comment: @Mulvya no luck with this trick too!

Comment: Share log with `-r 5`

Comment: @Mulvya thanks for your attention. I updated the question with `-r 5` output.

Comment: `-r 5` is for output, not input. Place it next to the pix_fmt.

Comment: @Mulvya sorry, my bad! I updated the output with correct command, but still not working. Strangely, I found if increasing the number of images and reduce the duration, it works (but I am not sure if it is persistent).

Comment: Remove the vsync but keep the r

Comment: @Mulvya didn't work again.

Comment: @Googlebot Add `-shortest` output option and use a recent ffmpeg. Using such an old version is a waste of time. Download a new version from [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), and optionally place it in `/usr/local/bin`. Let me know if it works or not.